# How to window.showDialog when wpf data binding in datagrid Row Details load

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, progress-bar

I'm binding an `ObservableCollection` of view models to it. Each view model has used for datagrid row details load.
When Data load for database then show `window.ShowDialog` and after for loop completed then auto window close

Answer (score -1):

For your case, you want to use `window.Show()` instead of `window.ShowDialog()`.

Here is the differences between them:

- **`window.Show();`**

The code doesn't stop. It means that you open the window and code continues is execution. In the example above, it will do next the "get data from database" and "for loop".
Using this method, the user can switch between windows in the application. Used when, an application execution proceeds normally

- **`window.ShowDialog();`**

The code stops until window is closed. It will execute the code from the new window, but in the examble above it will only continue to "get data from database" after the window is closed inside his code.
In this case, only the opened window responds to user input until it is closed

You should do something like this:

```
 Window win = new window();
 win.Show();

 //get data from database
 //do for loop

 win.Close();
```

Comment: This won't show the Window's Content unless you make sure the UI thread has a chance to run, e.g. by asynchronously getting data from the database.

Comment: Yes that's right, but the user in the question didn't mention that. My answer is correct  by what was asked.

Comment: No, not at all. Without mentioning the async aspect, it is only a bad advice. I'd be glad to remove my downvote if you edit your post accordingly.

Comment: And theres so many cases where you can get data from database without being asynchronously.